# Pie Chart in Android With MPAndroid library

Tags: android

I am having issue in MP Android Chart Library .

I have added this library in my Project .

```
implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.1.0'
```

But still i am not able use this in My XML file.

Comment: Go to File>Sync with gradle files. Something when you add library it did not sync.

Comment: if this work let me know. So ill post as answer.

Comment: Check have you added this  maven { url "https://jitpack.io" } too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you are missing Something in Gradle Setup

Do you have added this in build.Gradle(Project level).

```
repositories {
maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
}
```

If not then please add this and lemme know it is working or not.